# Subview within UIActionSheet isn't redrawn when setEnabled called

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

I have a button in search view controller that calls the following method that creates a `UIActionSheet` containing two `UISegmentedControl`s (used for selecting the Search Settings). When the user selects a certain button on the first segmented control, I want to disable (`setEnabled:NO`) the 2nd segmented control. The problem is that it doesn't redraw (and so it never gets disabled). If I setEnabled:NO initially when I create the UIActionSheet, it is correctly initially disabled.

I've tried forcing a redraw on both the 2nd segmented control and the action sheet by calling `[UIView setNeedsDisplay]`, but that's not working.

Also tried removeFromSuperview on the 2nd segmented control.

Is this not possible with the built-in UIActionSheet? Or is there a better way for me to show the search settings? This is an iPhone app coded for iOS5. Popovers don't work with iPhone. The other way I can think of is to have the settings show in it's own view, but I would like to avoid that.

```
-(void)onSettingsButtonClick:(id)sender
{
    // display segmented button views on actionSheet

    UIActionSheet *sheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:@"Search Settings" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Close" destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    sheet.actionSheetStyle = UIActionSheetStyleDefault;

    UISegmentedControl * segFullTextOrTags = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"Tags", @"Full Text", @"Users", nil]];
    [segFullTextOrTags addTarget:self action:@selector(onSegFullTextOrTagsClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [segFullTextOrTags setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    [segFullTextOrTags setTag:100];

    UISegmentedControl * segType2 = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"All Actions", @"Discussions", @"Responses", @"Comments", nil]];
    [segType2 addTarget:self action:@selector(onSegType2Clicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
    [segType2 setSegmentedControlStyle:UISegmentedControlStyleBar];
    [segType2 setTag:101];

    [sheet showFromTabBar:self.tabBarController.tabBar];

    // code that expands the action sheet height and adjusts the view positions is omitted here

    // add the additional views to the actionSheet
    [sheet addSubview:segFullTextOrTags];
    [sheet addSubview:segType2];
}

-(void)onSegFullTextOrTagsClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self updateSettingsUI:(UIActionSheet*)sender];
}

-(void)onSegType2Clicked:(id)sender
{
    [self updateSettingsUI:(UIActionSheet*)sender];
}

-(void)updateSettingsUI:(UIActionSheet*)actionSheet
{
    UISegmentedControl * segFullTextOrTags = (UISegmentedControl*)[actionSheet viewWithTag:100];
    UISegmentedControl * segType2 = (UISegmentedControl*)[actionSheet viewWithTag:101];

    if (segFullTextOrTags.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) // users
    {
        // disable 2nd segmented button control
        [segType2 setEnabled:NO];
    }
    else
    {
        // enable 2nd segmented button control
        [segType2 setEnabled:YES];
    }

    // doesn't work...
    [segType2 setNeedsDisplay];
    [actionSheet setNeedsDisplay];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think UIActionSheet is not the right control for presenting a settings view to the user.

From the class reference documentation:

> Use the UIActionSheet class to present the user with a set of
>   alternatives for how to proceed with a given task. You can also use
>   action sheets to prompt the user to confirm a potentially dangerous
>   action. The action sheet contains an optional title and one or more
>   buttons, each of which corresponds to an action to take.

Instead you should create a UIViewController subclass and present it modally or with a navigation controller.

I don't know why `setEnabled` is not working in your code. `setNeedsDisplay` is not necessary, the control should redraw itself. Check if segType2 in updateSettingsUI  and in onSettingsButtonClick is the same object.

Comment: The objects were different! I got it working simply by storing the UISegmentedControls in member var pointers and using those instead of viewWithTag. viewWithTag:101 must be returning a new instance. Strange, because the viewWithTag:100 seems to work... (segFullTextOrTags.selectedSegmentIndex == 2) evaluates to true within updateSettingsUI. Anyway, thanks! I'll also consider using a modal view controller subclass.